# How to get a percentage of total when the query has a GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a non-normalized table with movie actor names and the movies they've been in. eg.

```
CREATE TABLE movies_actors (
  movies_actors_id INT,
  movie VARCHAR(255),
  actor VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (movies_actors_id)
);
```

I do a `SELECT actor, COUNT(1) FROM movies_actors GROUP BY actor` to find out how many movies the actor has been in. But I also want to find out what percentage of movies that actor has been in.

I guess I could do this:

```
SELECT
  actor,
  COUNT(1) AS total,
  COUNT(1) / (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM movies_actors) * 100 AS avg
FROM movies_actors
GROUP BY actor;
```

But that just seems...  idk...  yucky.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note, that because of the way the MySQL engine works, `count(*)` will have exactly the same performance as `count(1)` and in my opinion is more semantically correct

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For large sets, a JOIN may perform better than the subquery.

```
SELECT ma.actor
     , COUNT(1) AS total
     , COUNT(1) / t.cnt * 100 AS `percentage`
  FROM movies_actors ma
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM movies_actors) t
 GROUP
    BY ma.actor
     , t.cnt
```

For large sets, and when a large percentage of the rows are being returned, the JOIN operation can usually outperform a subquery.  In your case, it's not a correlated subquery, so MySQL shouldn't have to execute that multiple times, so it may not make any difference.

Note to non-fans of `COUNT(1)`... we could replace any and all occurrences of `COUNT(1)` with `COUNT(*)` or `IFNULL(SUM(1),0)` to achieve equivalent result.

Comment: Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 't.cnt' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @brahimm:  to make the statement compatible, just add t.cnt to the GROUP BY clause. that is,  `GROUP BY ma.actor, t.cnt`.  The inline view (derived table) `t` is guaranteed to return exactly one row (if it runs successfully, or throw an error otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

Do a Self cross join whenever you want to get manipulated data from same table.

```
SELECT
m.actor,
COUNT(m.actor) AS total,
(COUNT(m.actor) / t.total_movies) * 100 AS avg
FROM movies_actors m
cross (select count(*) as total_movies from movies_actors) t
GROUP BY m.actor;
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using join and multiple query :-

```
select actor,counter,  100 * counter / @total as percentage
from(
select actor, 
        case when actor is null
            then @total := count(*)
            else count(*)
        end as counter
    from movies_actors 
    group by actor
    with rollup
) mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's any "better", but you could do a SUM and do the math elsewhere:

```
SELECT actor,
    COUNT(1) AS total,
    SUM(oneMoviePercentPts) AS percentage
FROM movies_actors
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT 100 / CAST(COUNT(1) AS DECIMAL(15,4)) AS oneMoviePercentPts 
    FROM movies_actors
) t
GROUP BY actor
```

I would hope the MySQL optimizer is smart enough to not execute your subquery more than once but the join syntax makes that explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT tmpTotal.yearmonth, tmpTotal.rec_count, 
      (tmpTotal.rec_count / @myCumul) * 100 AS myPercentage
FROM
(
  SELECT tmpResult.*, @myCumul := @myCumul + tmpResult.rec_count AS myNewCumul
  FROM
  (
    SELECT date_format(d.created_at, '%Y/%m') as yearmonth, count(*) rec_count
    FROM cf4a_webapp.factTable d 
      join cf4a_webapp.dimTable c on (d.client_id = c.id)
    WHERE c.id = 25 
      AND d.created_at >= '2019-01-01 00:00:01' 
      AND d.created_at < '2020-01-01 00:00:01'
    GROUP BY yearmonth
  ) tmpResult
  JOIN (SELECT @myCumul := 0) tmpCumul
) tmpTotal;
```