# stuck with calculation procent of sales per count () MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have 2 tables  t1 store data about customer (C_ID)transactions per seller (M_ID), T2 stores data about seller rating, what I am trying to do is calculate purchases for C_id and sellers ratings. 
I am able to calculate number of sales customer made per seller and sum of amout, but I also need to calculate how much procent (%) it is from all purchases made by customer

```
c_id | rating_cout | rating | sum | procent 
1 .  | 6 .         |  3 .   |20 . | 40%
1 .  | 5.          | 2 .    |50 . |30%
1 .  | 4 .         | 1 .    |30 . | 20%

SELECT 
    C_id,
    COUNT(t1.rating) AS rating_counts,
    t2.rating,
    SUM(t1.amount),
    count (proc) as proc-- need to do % calculation grouped by C_id and by rating 
FROM
    t1
        JOIN
    t2 ON t1.M_ID = t2.M_ID
GROUP BY C_id , t2.rating
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Just dont understand how to calculate this percentage

Comment: I don't know what procentage is  - is it short for pro-rata percentage or is it just a typo of percentage? Also it would help if you added sample data as text to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a percentage of total when the query has a GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516023/how-to-get-a-percentage-of-total-when-the-query-has-a-group-by)