# Using SQL to work out % of times a specific event occurrs

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hopefully you can help me, typically I do analysis in R and basic querying in SQL and have tripped myself up over what seems like a basic problem.

I have a basic table: table

```
ID    product  % discount (int)

1      a         10
2      a         0
3      a         5
4      b         0
5      b         5
6      b         5
7      c         0
```

I want to calculate the % of times a discount if applied by product. I have tried a number of approaches all either show incorrect values or error and I am unsure if it's syntax or approach driven.

Examples of erroneous code below, although please let me know if there  is an easier way.

I want to calculate the % of times a discount if applied by product. I have tried a number of approaches all either show incorrect values or error and I am unsure if it's syntax or approach driven.

```
SELECT count(discount) as discountN where discount > 0,
       count(discountN) * 100.0 / (select count(product_id) from table) as percent
FROM table
group by ID
```

---

with total as select count(*) as total from table
select count(discount) / total 
WHERE discount > 0
FROM table
group by ID

I am expecting:

```
a: 66%
b: 66%
c: 0%
```

Comment: MySql <> SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a percentage of total when the query has a GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516023/how-to-get-a-percentage-of-total-when-the-query-has-a-group-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below using `case when`

```
SELECT product,
       (count(case when discount > 0 then discount end) * 100.0) / count(product_id) as percent
FROM table
group by product
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ratio with discounts greater than 0, then I recommend `avg()`:

```
SELECT product,
       AVG(CASE WHEN discount > 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY product;
```

If you want values from 0 to 100 rather than 0 to 1, then use `100.0` rather than `1.0`.

In MySQL, this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT product,
       AVG( discount > 0 ) as ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY product;
```