# In SQL, how can I write a query to determine the percentage of a certain value in a column after I have queried its COUNT?

Tags: mysql, sql

-- Here's my code:

```sql
SELECT
COUNT(Action_taken)
FROM
Friend_requests
WHERE action_taken = “Accepted”
```

-- How can I write a second query to determine the percentage of values that equal "accepted"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a percentage of total when the query has a GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516023/how-to-get-a-percentage-of-total-when-the-query-has-a-group-by)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is conditional aggregation.  In MySQL, you can express this as:

```
select avg(action = 'accepted')
from friend_requests;
```

This works because MySQL treats boolean values as 1 for `true` and `0` for false.  So the average is the ratio of `true` values over all the values.

Note:  This will ignore `NULL` values for `action`.  That can trivially be handled using the `NULL`-safe comparison operator:

```
select avg(action <=> 'accepted')
from friend_requests;
```

Comment: Clever, but you'd probably want to be a little more explicit about how nulls are handled.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I added that.  But note that the question is using `count(action)`, so the OP is already ignoring `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    (select count(1) from friend_requests where action = "accepted")
    /
    (select count(1) from friend_requests)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff's answer and @Strawberry's comment, The ful query for me kinda like:

```
select round(avg(action = 'accepted') * 100, x)
from friend_requests
where action_taken is not null
```

- x is how many numbers after decimal